# Generate a CSV file which columns with no null values in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a dynamic source table, some columns might have a null value 
For example

```
╔════════════════════╗
║ Name Grade1 Grade2 ║
╠════════════════════╣
║ Tom   85      null ╣
║ Tom   null    95   ╣
╚════════════════════╝
```

Then I want to generate a CSV/flat file as my destination table with a comma delimiter
how can I hide the columns which have no value there?

For example, the output of the table above will be

```
╔══════════════╗
║ Name  Grade1 ║
╠══════════════╣
║ Tom   85     ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Or

```
╔══════════════╗
║ Name  Grade2 ║
╠══════════════╣
║ Tom   95     ║
╚══════════════╝
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. When you say you have `dynamic source table` what does that mean? Does it mean tomorrow there will be Grade3? What should happen in the output file if Tom has an 85 for Grade1 and 95 for Grade2 - what goes into the output file? If both, what happens with Harry who only has a value in Grade1? How do they get into the same output file with that NULL for Grade2.

Comment: Does your import and export only have one row?

Comment: I think your easiest option would be to get rid of the nulls in your SQL extract query because it seems like your data is the result of a pivot query,

Comment: @KeithL Sorry I just re-edit the contents.